# Multiplication of two numbers without using MUL instruction

Tags: assembly, cpu, multiplication

I have to write program (for both SIC and SIC/XE machine)

I try to wrote it by using  a shl operation that performs the same operation as multiplying the specified operand by two. Shifting to the left two bit positions multiplies the operand by four. Shifting to the left three bit positions multiplies the operand by eight. In general, shifting an operand to the left n bits multiplies it by 2n. Any value can be multiplied by some constant using a series of shifts and adds or shifts and subtractions. For example, to multiply the ax register by ten, you need only multiply it by eight and then add in two times the original value. That is, 10*ax = 8*ax + 2*ax. The code to accomplish this is

```
            shl     ax, 1           ;Multiply AX by two
            mov     bx, ax          ;Save 2*AX for later
            shl     ax, 1           ;Multiply AX by four
            shl     ax, 1           ;Multiply AX by eight
            add     ax, bx          ;Add in 2*AX to get 10*AX
```

Now how can I write a program (SIC and SIC/EX machine)?
Could you please someone help me?

Comment: That is x86 code, but the logic is valid. So, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Someone might answer you, but this isn't what SO is really about.  To obtain actual assistance, you should try to write it yourself and then post when you run into trouble.  This isn't a language teaching site, nor is it a "write this code for me" site.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding/algorithm is on the right track.  Remember grade school, except base 2 is so much easier.

```
        abcd
    *   1101
    =========
        abcd
       0000
      abcd
+    abcd
=============
```

which is also

```
abcd * ghef = (abcd*(f*(2^0)))+(abcd*(e*(2^1)))+(abcd*(h*(2^2)))+(abcd*(g*(2^3)))
```

so take one of the numbers walk a one through it if that bit is set add the other number shifted the same amount to your accumulator.

```
//a = op1 * op2 in binary
a=0;
b=op1;
for(x=1;x;x<<=1)
{
   if(x&op2) a+=b;
   b<<=1;
}
```

so just implement that in whatever language with whatever instructions.

Comment: It's normally easier to right-shift `a` and always check its low bit.  (Or even take advantage of `shr` setting CF = the low bit shifted out)